cypress with cucumber package.json step_definitions not being found with subfolders
I apologise if this question has been answered elsewhere or is incomplete but I couldn't find an answer to my issue, as simple as it may seem.
I have made a new cypress project using cucumber feature files and been able to get my tests working if I place it all in to the e2e folder (with step_definitions = "cypress/e2e/*"), but when I put my specs in to subfolders to split out my tests (i.e. e2e/account/... and e2e/booking/...), it doesn't seem to find my spec files no matter what I put in step_definitions.
I've tried "cypress/e2e/*/*", "cypress/e2e/**/*", "cypress/e2e/**" etc. in the step_definitions value in package.json but not sure if I'm just getting it wrong and misunderstanding... Is it possible to split this out or not?
For reference, This is my folder structure
My package.json looks like this ;
{
  "name": "Cypress.Tests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^13.15.1",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor":{
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
    "step_definitions": "cypress/e2e/*" <-- My issue 
  }
}

and my cypress.config.js if relevant looks like this ;
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
      on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
    },
    specPattern: "cypress/e2e/*.feature",
  },
});

